# What is this GUID?

Tags: windows, registry, device-driver, windows-explorer, network-drive

After connect a network-drive, when we open a Windows Explorer or a File Dialog, 
the process find this key in the registry to show it's volume name.

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\{**A45BA3B2-F3
>   96-4F67-8375-ECC2CA1EBBFC**}\_LabelFromReg

I don't know what the GUID is.

- What is it?
- Who(When) does create the key?
- How does the application(in this case, Windows Explorer) know the key?

I'm developing a network-redirector like SMB.
I should write a volume name to the key.
Once my network volume connected, the registry key also created. (of cource the GUID is different with SMB's. It even changes whenever each connection created and deleted)
But I don't know how I can get the my volume's(?) GUID.(Even who creates the key)

I tried to find DefineDosDeviceW(suspected) in ReactOS source. But it hasn't implemented yet. T.T

-Of course, I also write the volume name to **\MountPoints2\##UNCNAME\_LabelFromReg**
But it doesn't work for WOW64 applications in 64Bit Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a specific GUID; it's a volume identifier. Windows Explorer creates these keys when volumes are mounted. You can see a list of currently mounted volume IDs by running `mountvol` without parameters. Programmatically (on Win32 level), you can obtain it with [FindFirstVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364425%28VS.85%29.aspx) and friends. I don't know anything about network redirector; however, it doesn't seem right to poke within Explorer registry key manually. It's Explorer's private territory. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a documented API for that.

Comment: I have to write to the key to represent my volume name in Apps. In only Wow64 Apps's dialog, our volume name is not shown well. Thanks I'll try FindFirstVolume and his friends :)

Comment: I tried but it wasn't. It's different with volume identifier.

Comment: @Benjamin - maybe it's different for win64? Because for me key name does match volume id... Unfortunately I don't have win64 handy to check.

Comment: How did you know this is a volume identifier and not a 'specific' GUID (as opposed to an unspecific one, whatever that is)?

Comment: @Unknow0059 Ugh, six years has flown, I don't even remember writing this answer... By "not a specific GUID", I guess, I meant that this GUID value is not a value with a special meaning, predefined by Microsoft; just a general value, taken from the volume id.

Comment: @Unknow0059 As for how I know; I'm sorry, I can't cite a source now (6 years...) However checking right now, on an AMD64 Windows10, I still see these values matching volume IDs. And I still wouldn't recommend touching the undocumented innards of the Explorer if you're doing anything beyond a throwaway toy project. There [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34201648/23252) to be a semi-supported way of doing that via WMI though, which may or may not work depending on the nature of the volume.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394515(v=vs.85)