# How do I programmatically change the label of a mapped drive?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing a piece of software which maps a network drive using the [WNetAddConnection2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  API. Just in case it's relevant, this is a WebDAV drive, rather than a normal SMB share.

The drive takes on a default name which I'd like to change.

Some answers on the net recommend using System.IO.DriveType, e.g:

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

foreach (var drive in allDrives)
{
    if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Network && drive.Name.StartsWith("Z:"))
    {
        drive.VolumeLabel = "DriveInfo";
    }
}
```

This unequivically does not work on network drives, and this backed up by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.volumelabel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where it's stated that an `UnauthorizedAccessException` Exception will be thrown.

Secondly, I attempted to use the shell method:

```
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
((Shell32.Folder2) shell.NameSpace("Z:")).Self.Name = "Shell";
```

The code executes with no errors, but the drive is not renamed. And this is where it gets weird, I found the registry path where these things get written:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ Software\ Microsoft\ Windows\ CurrentVersion\ Explorer\ MountPoints2`

The code above creates a key which looks correct, and adds a `_LabelFromReg` REG_SZ with "Shell" as the value. However, this is NOT reflected in Explorer or anywhere else.

I then manually renamed the mapped the drive, by right clicking and selecting "Rename".

Doing so creates a new, slightly different key within `MountPoints2` which works perfectly.

So, the shell code above isn't quite resolving the path correctly - is there something else I can try? The above leads me to believe Windows must use a different API call internally to rename the drive?

---

**Update 1**

This is definitely related to these being WebDAV drives. There must be some under-the-hood processing going on.

My software maps `https://myurl.com@ssl/stuff/destination/docs`. That exact path can be seen with the `Net Use` command. It's this path that the `shell` code above adds to the registry and attempts to name.

However, hovering over the drive in Windows Explorer gives me `https://myurl.com@ssl/anotherfolder/stuff/destination` and it's this path which renaming manually within Explorer adds to the registry.

All I've managed to figure out so far is how to return the second path from a WMI (Win32_LogicalDisk -> ProviderName) call, but I really want to avoid the manual registry entry approach.

Comment: Is this "other folder" by chance called "DavWWWRoot" ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use PowerShell in your C# code, the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx

Change DriveLetter `E` to `Q` with PowerShell

```
$drive = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'e:'"
Set-WmiInstance -input $drive -Arguments @{DriveLetter="Q:"; Label="Label"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old already but I had exactly the same issue with the renaming of a webdav drive letters and found a solution.

The problem occurs, if you ever connected your webDav drive with the address like:
`https://www.myurl.com:5006/myFolder`

Using this url-scheme will result in an registry entry in:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2`
A "DavWWWRoot" will automatically inserted into your given address:
`##myurl.com@SSL@5006#DavWWWRoot#myFolder`
Also if you remove this drive, the RegistryEntry persists and will prevent you from renaming the drive via script also if you already made it to mount a drive with a registry-entry without the "DavWWWRoot" string in it. (using different url-scheme)

When you try to automatically rename the drives label with the method showed by Dan, the new name will be placed unter a new RegistryEntry with a different path (without the "DavWWWRoot") and the new name will not be used.

The solution is:

1. Unmount your webDav-drives you want to rename.
2. Delete the RegistryEntries with the DAVWWWRoot in it for all your drives you want to rename from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2´
3. Mount your webDav-drives with a slightly adapted url-scheme. For our example use a url-scheme like this one:
   `\\www.myurl.com@SSL@5006\myFolder`
4. Check if a registry-entry was added without "DAVWWWRoot" in it. Should be:
   `##myurl.com@SSL@5006#myFolder`
5. Now you can go and rename your drive-label with the method of Dan:
   `Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
   ((Shell32.Folder2) shell.NameSpace("Z:")).Self.Name = "Shell";`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (i dont use C#), when i connect a server : `net use z: http://example.com:8000 /user:user password` then windows show "DAVWWWRoot" in the explorer.

I add this in the registry to rename :

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##example.com@8000#DavWWWRoot" /v "_LabelFromReg" /t REG_SZ /d "Weytop Drive" /f
```

Explore the registry to see where you need to set this _LabelFromReg key.